# How is Alice still alive at the end of "Resident Evil 6"?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

It was mentioned that Alice binds with the T-virus at a cellular level.

However, at the end of the movie it's said that the antivirus kills only T-virus but leaves the healthy cells. It should kill all of Alice's cells because the virus and her cells are bound. As a result, Alice will be dead.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I'd assume the logic is that when she binds with the T-virus on a cellular level there's no longer any T-virus remaining, and instead she has some new kind of cell (that's considered healthy). There's therefore nothing for the antivirus to kill.

Comment: That sounds like a legit explanation. But in that case, Wesker won't be able to cure her (in Resident Evil 3 I think) and then give back her ability (at the end of Resident Evil 5)...right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies within Alice, she is "technically" alive.

What I mean technically is, she is not dead yet she is infected by the T-Virus. Unlike zombies that are dead, and the flying moths that are composed and living AND relying with the T-virus to stay alive, Alice is human, a clone to be exact, but she has red blood cells, all the cells a human has. What actually happened to Alice is she became a normal human after resident Evil 6.

Do also take note that Albert Wesker removed the T-Virus inside her in Resident evil 4:Afterlife when Wesker is trying to escape and Alice surprises him from behind, he injects Alice with a serum that neutralizes the T-Virus inside her, making her human again.

Comment: So, simply speaking, although "Alice binds with the T-virus at a cellular level", it could be "unbound". They are not like merged or depend on each other in any way. I think too much haha. It's a good point of view from the "living thing".

Comment: @PhoenixPan if you think about it, after maybe 10 years of being a zombie in the Resident evil universe, their blood has been drained already, yet they still walk. Which we may point out that the T-Virus keeps them alive, Alice is a different species however, because she is human, but very super human.

Comment: Haha yeah, perhaps I should worry more about what's the energy source that keeps those zombies moving :P